# Adding OR condition to query slows it down

Tags: mysql, pdo

i added an OR condition to a query and querys execution time is reached to 15+ seconds from less than 0.5 seconds. All columns being used in where clause are indexed. Wondering how can i optimize this query.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(DISTINCT wo.id) AS totrows
FROM wo

LEFT JOIN wu
ON wu.id = wo.id

LEFT JOIN bu
ON bu.id = wu.id

LEFT JOIN ub
ON ub.uid = bu.id

JOIN u
ON u.id = wo.created_by

LEFT JOIN ws
ON ws.wo_id = wo.id, b

WHERE (wo.bid = '13'
AND (wo.created_by IN('2506') OR wo.uid IN('2506') )
AND wo.status != 5
AND ( wo.uid = '' || wu.uid in ( '406', 0) || wo.uid IS NULL )
AND wo.ut = 0
AND ( (wo.wt = 'unit' AND (wo.archive != 1 OR wo.archive IS NULL) ) OR wo.wt = 'common' )) OR (ws.uid = 2506 )
```

Removing `OR (ws.uid = 2506 )` makes query very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (Query1 union Query2)` like this. Looks good so far.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totrows FROM (
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(DISTINCT wo.id) AS totrows
    FROM wo

    LEFT JOIN wu
    ON wu.id = wo.id

    LEFT JOIN bu
    ON bu.id = wu.id

    LEFT JOIN ub
    ON ub.uid = bu.id

    JOIN u
    ON u.id = wo.created_by

    LEFT JOIN ws
    ON ws.wo_id = wo.id

    WHERE (wo.bid = '13'
    AND (wo.created_by IN('2506') OR wo.uid IN('2506') )
    AND wo.status != 5
    AND ( wo.uid = '' || wu.uid in ( '406', 0) || wo.uid IS NULL )
    AND wo.ut = 0
    AND ( (wo.wt = 'unit' AND (wo.archive != 1 OR wo.archive IS NULL) ) OR wo.wt = 'common' )) OR (ws.uid = 2506 )

    UNION

    select DISTINCT wo.id from wo LEFT JOIN ws ON ws.wo_id = wo.id WHERE ws.uid = 2506

) AS T
```